# Метод Stream и динамический двумерный массив данных из файл

Tags: java, java-stream

Имеется файл с данными о смартфонах(Серийный номер, Производитель, Модель, Операционная система, Объем оперативной памяти). Вопрос: как поместить этот массив в Stream? Форма, которой должен пользоваться Stream:

```
package org.FinalProgram;

public class FormForBox {

    public int number;
    public String maker;
    public String model;
    public String os;
    public int ram;


    public FormForBox (int number, String maker, String model, String os, int ram){
        this.number = number;
        this.maker = maker;
        this.model = model;
        this.os = os;
        this.ram = ram;

    }

    //getters
    public int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
    public String getMaker(){
        return maker;
    }
    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }
    public String getOs(){
        return os;
    }
    public int getRam(){
        return ram;
    }


    //setters
    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number=number;
    }
    public void setMaker(String maker){
        this.maker=maker;
    }
    public void setModel(String model){
        this.model=model;
    }
    public void setOs(String os){
        this.os=os;
    }
    public void setRam(int ram){
        this.ram=ram;
    }

}
```

Пробовал делать вот так:

```
  String sCurrentLine;
            File inputFile = new File("C:\\data\\data.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

            while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] params = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                Stream<FormForBox> streamPhone = Stream.of( new FormForBox ( Integer.parseInt( params[0]), params[1], params[2], params[3], Integer.parseInt( params[4])) );
            }
                reader.close();
```

Но следующая строка не видит streamPhone:

```
Map<String, List<FormForBox>> phonesByMaker = streamPhone.collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(FormForBox::getMaker));
```

Comment: Потому что он существует только внутри блока кода, который, возможно, никогда и не выполнится. Вам нужно сделать Iterable<>, который потом оборачивать через StreamSupport, либо создать пустой стрим и конкатенировать его на каждой итерации через Stream.concat

Comment: @Etki, можно по конкретнее? Просто я в javа yновичок совсем

Comment: Можно просто `Files.lines()` или `BufferedReader.lines()` вызвать.

Comment: @zRrr, может быть и можно, но я вас не понимаю) Можно по конкретнее, что и куда.

Answer (score 1):

Объявленная в блоке переменная существует только в пределах этого блока. В вашем случае `streamPhone` перестаёт существовать после завершения блока `while`.

И, как верно заметил zRrr, у вас наворочено много лишнего. Можно проще

```
Stream<FormForBox> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\data\\data.txt"))
  .map(s -> s.split(" "))
  .filter(a -> a.length == 5)
  .map(a -> new FormForBox(Integer.parseInt(a[0]), a[1], a[2], a[3], Integer.parseInt(a[4])));
```

Ещё лучше, если бы можно было добавить в `FormForBox` конструктор принимающий массив

```
public class FormForBox {
    ...

    public FormForBox(String[] fields) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (fields.length != 5)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Полей должно быть ровно 5!");

        this.number = Integer.parseInt(number);
        this.maker = maker;
        this.model = model;
        this.os = os;
        this.ram = Integer.parseInt(ram);
    }

    ...
}
```

Тогда создание стрима стало бы выглядеть компактнее и красивее

```
Stream<FormForBox> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\data\\data.txt"))
                                 .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                                 .filter(a -> a.length == 5)
                                 .map(FormForBox::new);
```